# Android add EditText dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

at the click of the button, I want to create EDITTEXT dynamically and display them vertically. I have this code but it just creates one EditText. Where am I wrong? Thanks for your help.

```
private LinearLayout containerLayout;
static int totalEditTexts = 0;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_category);
    containerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            totalEditTexts++;

            EditText editText = new EditText(getBaseContext());
            containerLayout.addView(editText);
            editText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            layoutParams.setMargins(23, 34, 0, 0);

            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            editText.setTag("EditText" + totalEditTexts);
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: What is the orientation of `relative1` and why are you setting the layout params after adding the EditText. What also makes me scratch my head is  the name "relative" for a `LinearLayout`

Comment: You must give witdh and height to a view.You gave only width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works perfectly if your `add_category.xml` were to look like this:
https://gist.github.com/akodiakson/9d37e3e48d0798d106c3

So I'm guessing your `Activity` layout might be a little bit off.